# How can I understand "could have been reached had Nazi discipline?"

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrase-meaning

While I was reading a book, I found a sentence incomprehensible.
It reads,
"A danger point could have been reached had Nazi discipline and its totalitarian control been relaxed."

I can understand the meaning only vaguely through the context, though, still I'm not sure what the "had Nazi discipline" is meant to be.

And what's the exact grammatical structure of it?

Thanks!

Comment: "A danger point could have been reached had Nazi discipline and its totalitarian control been relaxed." is just a variant of  "A danger point could have been reached if Nazi discipline and its totalitarian control had been relaxed."

Comment: Oh now I see that I've been completely wrong about the sentence! So much thanks to you.

Comment: This is exactly what I was finding for. Thank you for reminding me!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Inversion